# How to get the name of the object from its coordinates (in object mode)?

Tags: objects

How can I find the name of an object given certain coordinates?
What if there was more than one object with its origin at that point?

Thank you and I apologize for any errors: translated with PC!

Answer (score 2):

**All objects with origin within a tolerance of cursor.**

Simple script to make a list of all objects whose origin is within a tolerance `TOL` of the `scene.cursor_location`.

```
import bpy

from bpy import context
scene = context.scene

TOL = 0.1 # get all objects within 0.1 bu of loc
#use cursor for location
loc = scene.cursor_location

obs_in_location = [o for o in scene.objects
        if (o.matrix_world.translation - loc).length < TOL]

print(len(obs_in_location), " at ", loc)
if len(obs_in_location):
    for o in obs_in_location:
        print("\t", o.name)
```

Comment: Thank you,
but I don't want to use the mouse position: I have a series of coordinates (x, y, z) and I would like to know from script if in a given position there is an object and if there is its name.

Comment: It's not the mouse position it's the 3D cursor. Edit such that `loc = (x, y, z)` then.  The 3D cursor position was only being used as a basic example.  There are no coordinates in question.

Comment: !!! sorry! Grazie.